# M2 Change layout of category page with XML

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

I have created a page http://www.extenderstore.com.au/shipping.html and I would like to change the `layout` to **2 columns with left bar**. I made a file in `Magento_Catalog/layout/` called `catalog_category_view.xml` with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head></head>
<body></body>
```

But it's not working?

Comment: is it a category or cms page?

Comment: it is a category page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change layout of category from admin, follow below steps-

1. Go To **Products -> Categories**
2. Select your Category, for which you want to change layout.
3. Select Design tab
4. uncheck **Use Parent Category Settings**, if checked
5. from layout select **2columns-left** and save category

**Update:-** if you check the **Luma** theme's layout for category view page at path-

> /your_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

you can see that category description block  `category.description` and static block content `category.cms` are added under `<referenceContainer name="columns.top">`

So you if you want to add them under main content you have to override `catalog_category_view.xml` to move both those block under `<referenceContainer name="content">`

**you can add below code in your layout to move them to the content block**

```
<move element="category.description" destination="content" as="category_description" />
<move element="category.cms" destination="content" after="category_description" />
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: did you run setup:upgrade command after applying chnages?

Comment: yes I did. I do so for all theme changes

Comment: I visited the url you mentioned it is 2columns-left layout,  as your `<body>` tag has class `page-layout-2columns-left`

Comment: So why is the text 1 column?

Comment: as per luma theme , the category description is added above the content area, so it is spread in full content area, if you add products/static block to the category , that content will display as 2column, also currently, compare product and  wishlist block are displaying in left column but you have not added any content to the main block

Comment: thats why there is blank space on right

Comment: I have added a static block with text "This is a static block" and it still shows as 1 column

Comment: I tried but still not showing on frontend although I cleared cache

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
       </body>
    </page>
```

Should be enough, have you cleared your cache after your change?
You can also try clearing `var/*` and `pub/static` followed by a `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I have done all those things but the text I enter in the "Content" tab of the category is still one column

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to set up your layout for category page

1. From admin panel for specific category.
2. With code for setting a parent layout of to be followed from all the categories.

Here is the way to set the layout

**From admin panel for specific category.**

```
 1. go to admin panel
 2. Products > categories
 3. Select the category for which you want to set the layout as you wanted
 4. Design > Layout >Select the desired Layout
 5. Save the Category.
```

**With code for setting a parent layout of to be followed from all the categories.**(Recommended)

1. Create a directory structure in your own theme as

   app\design\frontend\Vendor\Module\Magento_catalog\layout
2. create a file there with name `catalog_category_view.xml`
3. Put this code into the file

   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="html/title.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   <move element="category.description" destination="content" after="page.main.title"/>
       </body>
   </page>`
4. Run this command

   `php bin/magento cache:clean`
5. Refresh your that category page

Comment: I have done this. How can I add a block now with content which is in the second column?

Comment: your layout is already in the following the 2columns-left layout just simply put this `<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="page.main.title"/>` code between the reference container than you will be able to see the effect.

Comment: you can simply add a product also to see the page layout of your category page