# How to change category page block after opening shop by filter

Tags: magento2, category, page

I'm new Magento2 User and I got an issue.

You can see the picture [image: oldcategorypage] it shows before I open Shop By filter.

After opening that,I add new Category and the page goes left-right bolck style [image: newcategorypage].

How can I change the old category page to left-right bolck style.

Comment: i think you are set the category layout

Comment: where i can edit the category layout? I want to check.

Comment: go to admin panel and open the catalog > categories > select any specific category and see this https://prnt.sc/slm59e

Comment: I change all layout and the front page doesn't changed so add new category with No layout updates and the front page goes left-right block.

Comment: check this --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195484/m2-change-layout-of-category-page-with-xml

Comment: It works when i clean the cache. thanks

Comment: i add answer and you are accept ???

Comment: sure go to answer. The ture is you help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your admin panel `catalog > categories > select any specific category` and see the design step and change the you want to layout

[image]

After run the

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this help

Thanks ...